# Unix standard output tab delimited

Tags: unix, tabs, standards, output

does anyone know of a unix command that can insert special characters like tab between  the output of another command like `ls`
so that the output looks like

a tab b tab c
instead of
a
b
c

Comment: if you want to insert tab's into your ls output, you need to show that in your example. If you're using a file with line per data elem, which is what your sample data looks like, you need to indicate that in your problem description. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the command, there's nothing general. Try this to convert newlines to tabs:

```
ls | tr "\n" "\t"
```